# Provisioning for Xamarin iOS - profiles existing but not recognized by VS2019

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2019, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

This is a copy of the question i asked on Xamarin forums with no luck yet, so here it is here too.

I have:

```
VS2019 paired to Mac (in cloud, no physical access)
Apple developer account
Followed manual and automatic provisioning guides on Microsoft's web site
Set up several development and distributions certificates, identity, app id, etc., with matching bundle id (info.plist, develeoper portal etc)
```

I have two scenarios:
1) With automatic provisioning in bundle signing the process completed successfully, but when i try to archive i get the error "codesign exited with code 1
2) With manual provisioning I can select various signing identities but either get:
a) no provisioning profile if i select distribution identity, or
b) unknown - and then in brackets various profiles i tried to create during the course of the nightmare

When i check options->xamarin->apple accounts i can see several distribution and development profiles and certificates.

[Profiles and certificates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNg2i.png)

Can anyone help me get to the bottom of this? I have probably not included everything that people might think it's relevant so just ask away what else should i post. I can also live chat or talk on skype or whatsapp, or call someone internationally, or whatever other method you find most suitable.

Comment: If it wasn't clear - I don't have physical access to Mac, so i can't plug in iPhone into it. Now wondering if that's got something to do with it.

Comment: Which version of Visual-Studio are you using? Have a look at [this discussion](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/957696/xamarin-ios-provisioning-profile-not-showing-when.html) and try the suggestions there may help.

Comment: It's 2019 and I did read but it does not apply to my situation. Currently deleting everything and trying to set up new profiles, certs, etc.

Comment: Try the latest version again and if the problem still there, report a problem to [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).